# Transparent image not transparent in HTML page

Tags: html

I have problems with the following HTML-code that outputs an [image containing table](https://gofile.io/?c=8z8xd4):

```
<html><body>
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <th text-align='left'>TITLE</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><img src='https://c7.uihere.com/files/740/842/424/american-red-cross-international-red-cross-and-red-crescent-movement-clip-art-red-cross-thumb.jpg' style='background:transparent;'/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<body></html>
```

1) I'm using the transparent image, but it doesn't display it as a transparent (shows it still as a checkered image). Why is it so?
2) Also, I'm using the text-align='left' attribute, but it doesn't affect the table's title position and it's still aligned in center.

Any ideas what is wrong in my code?

Comment: The image is not transparant. Its a `jpg` image. check for `png` format

Comment: I checked the url of the image provided. It shows the checked background as well. Try with a different image.

Comment: The file extension is jpg which is not transparently supported.

Comment: @Jane Mänd this may help you https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729433/html-png-image-transparent&hl=en-IN&tg=82

Comment: Your code is correct. You dont need to have `background: transparent;` in your image tag. Try using https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/proglyphs-free/512/Linux_-_Tux-512.png image as sample and give a background color to the `td` element. You can see the transparancy of the image is working fine.

Comment: But how to make sure that image is transparent or not? Just by using a trial error method? And what about this text alignment problem?

Comment: Please read my answer. A jpg is *never* transparent.

Answer (score 0):

It does make any sense using a `style=background:transparent` on an img tag. Every tag-element itself is transparent else not defined otherwise.

But the image you are providing is not transparent at all. JPG format does not support transparency (because it has no alpha channel).

Use a common image format who does support transparency like png, webp or gif.